# Facebook login 500 internal server error

Tags: facebook, authentication

my facebook page gives 500 internal error, and cannot log in. It was after using application "who visits my page". I cannot even use facebook help, anytime I try to log in, it gives me message(see attachment).

[image]

Comment: Wrong SE.  Try this one over on WebApps

Answer (score 2):

Clear your chrome cookies and restart your browser and try again.

Comment: If it doesn't help try opening fecebook w/ chome's [Incoginto Mode](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464)